# Externalize DWL for Set Variable and Object Store Default Value Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

Is it possible to externalize value for the **Set Variable** component as well as the **Object Store** default value? I only used externalization of DWL for **Transform Message** component but I havent tried it using to the other components.

```
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message">
   <ee:message>
      <ee:set-payload resource="test.dwl"/>
   </ee:message>
</ee:transform>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can externalize value for any connector where expression mode is possible for the value, for that purpose you will have to use "[readUrl()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-readurl)" function.

For example,

```
readUrl("classpath://myfile.dwl","application/json")
```

You can give the location of your externalized dwl file as classpath

Answer (score 0):

You can use a value from a [configuration property](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/configuring-properties) in the set-variable value o object store default.

Example:

```
<set-variable variableName="a" value="${myprop}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-language-introduction#dwl_file), you can use the `${file::fileName}` syntax to externalise the DW scripts from all the other components.

Examples for the components you've mentioned:

- Set Variable

```xml
<set-variable value="#[${file::fooBar.dwl}]" doc:name="foo" variableName="foo" />
```

- Object Store Default Value

```xml
<os:default-value ><![CDATA[#[${file::dw/objectStore/retrieveItemDefaultValue.dwl}]]]></os:default-value>
```